# How to access one application server which is behind vpn server without connecting to the vpn?

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn

I have a requirement where I want to access one application which is behind the vpn without connecting to the vpn. First is this possible and if it is, please tell me the way to do that? What the configuration required at vpn server? I am using openVPN for the vpn setup.

Can split tunneling be a solution here?

Comment: What issues do you have with "joining the vpn"? Do you define this as connecting to the VPN, or do you define this as routing all traffic through the VPN?

Comment: @user1686 I define it as connecting to the VPN.

Comment: Why do you think they are using a VPN?

Comment: You would need to expose the application to the regular internet. Anyone could connect to it. You would need to change the service configuration in a way that allows it to be directly accessible. You might be able to employ a reverse proxy depending on the scenario.

Comment: @Seth Appreciate your reply. We have already employed the reverse proxy at the application service. Do you think any configuration is required at the vpn server side?

Comment: That heavily depends on your setup, probably not. But without knowing the circumstances and setup it's hard to say. In addition it's unclear what service you're talking about and what you're trying to achieve and why.

Comment: @Seth There is a client UI application which is currently behind the vpn, because the backend server application and the db is also behind the vpn. So for easy communication among those, I have kept them behind the vpn. But user wants to use client UI application without connecting to the VPN. Now currently, it's not supportable but could you suggest me how to do that?

Comment: That's already being described in my first comment. It's up to you to make the changes and decide which option is suitable for your needs.